# Resizing VStack to match LazyVGrid Element

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a lazyVGrid that has 3 flexible columns elements with an aspect ratio of 1. The container around it is fixed vertically. I am trying to resize the elements on the VStack to its left to have an aspect ratio of 1 so that its height matches the grid element size. The last picture is what I'm going for (its hardcoded with .frame() to illustrate the point)

```
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(answerRows, id: \.self) { row in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
            .border(.orange, width: 2)
            .padding(.leading, 40)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {   // RESIZE BASED ON GRID SIZE
                    ForEach(answerRows, id: \.self) { row in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill) //This is the issue
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .border(.purple, width: 1)
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(answerRows.flatMap{$0}, id: \.self) { row in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                                .border(Color(red: 29/255, green: 29/255, blue: 40/255), width: 3)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 69/255))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))                   
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .border(.green, width: 1)
        }
        .border(.blue, width: 1)
    }
```

This ends up being the result:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GeometryReader` to get the width size.
Based on your code, I modified it a little to get the result as the picture that you provided.

I hope it is useful for you.

```
struct GridView: View {
    
    let answerRows = 1...3
    let threeColumnGrid = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    let data = 1...9
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let widthSize = geometry.size.width
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(answerRows, id: \.self) { row in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: widthSize/8).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: widthSize/4)
                .border(.orange, width: 2)
                .padding(.leading, widthSize/4)
                
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(answerRows, id: \.self) { row in
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: widthSize / 14).foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: widthSize/4, maxHeight: widthSize)
                    .border(.purple, width: 1)
                    
                    LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid) {
                        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { row in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 69/255))
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: widthSize * 3 / 4, maxHeight: widthSize)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .border(.green, width: 1)
            }
            .border(.blue, width: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]